# How to use ASP membership to control the which widgets should be loaded on the website?

Tags: c#, silverlight, membership

Our company use ASP membership as password protection for our Silverlight websites. What I want is that different user see different widgets (i.e., some widgets are not loaded to some users who don't have privilege). This means, how can I control which widgets should be loaded to the website when people access the silverlight website based on their privilege. Can this be fulfilled by ASP membership or how should I fulfill it?

Many thanks for your help in advance.

Wei

Comment: are you using RIA services? or can you use it?

Comment: Yes, I can, but how to implement it. Can I read ASP membership info from client silverlight code (I doubt it)?

Comment: check the answer i just posted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can access asp.net membership in silverlight using RIA services. you will have to create Membership DTO and then you can pass all membership provider entities all the way to silverlight.

http://leeontech.wordpress.com/2009/03/25/using-aspnet-membership-and-profile-providers-with-ria-services/

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kylemc/archive/2010/05/10/using-asp-net-membership-in-silverlight.aspx